# Recursively remove all adjacent duplicate numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I want to recursively remove all adjacent duplicate numbers in an array

I have gone through similar links where they did this on strings

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/

Below is the code for removing adjacent duplicates in a string, I was wondering if there is an ideal way to go along the same lines but run it over an array

```
  static String removeUtil(String str, char last_removed) 
  { 
         // If length of string is 1 or 0  
         if (str.length() == 0 || str.length() == 1) 
             return str; 

         // Remove leftmost same characters and recur for remaining   
         // string  
         if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1)) 
         { 
             last_removed = str.charAt(0); 
             while (str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1)) 
                   str = str.substring(1, str.length()); 
             str = str.substring(1, str.length()); 
             return removeUtil(str, last_removed);  
         } 

         // At this point, the first character is definiotely different   
         // from its adjacent. Ignore first character and recursively   
         // remove characters from remaining string  
         String rem_str = removeUtil(str.substring(1,str.length()), last_removed); 

         // Check if the first character of the rem_string matches with   
         // the first character of the original string 
         if (rem_str.length() != 0 && rem_str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(0)) 
         { 
            last_removed = str.charAt(0); 
            return rem_str.substring(1,rem_str.length()); // Remove first character 
         }  


         // If remaining string becomes empty and last removed character  
         // is same as first character of original string. This is needed  
         // for a string like "acbbcddc"  
         if (rem_str.length() == 0 && last_removed == str.charAt(0)) 
             return rem_str; 

         // If the two first characters of str and rem_str don't match,   
         // append first character of str before the first character of  
         // rem_str 
         return (str.charAt(0) + rem_str); 
  }
```

Suppose if the input array is

1) [2,3,3] - output is [2]

2) [1,2,3,3,2] - [1,2,2] - output is [1]

3) [2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1] - output is []

Edit - If anyone is still looking for a solution, i figured one way out. I fixed the bug in @kemalturgul 's solution. This was working for me.

```
public static int[] removeUtil(int[] arr) 
{
    int i=0;
    boolean check = false;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) 
        {
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(check)
        return removeUtil(combineTwoArray(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, i), Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i + 2, arr.length)));
    else
        return arr;

}

public static int[] combineTwoArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length + arr2.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) 
        newArr[arr1.length + j] = arr2[j];

    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively when an iterative method would be simpler to understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply with [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

Just put each number from the array on the stack, check for duplicate numbers at each iteration on the top of the stack and, if found, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a direct translation where you accept an `int[]` instead of `String` is possible.

I suppose that the translations of `str.length()` and `str.charAt(index)` are trivial.

For `str.substring(1, str.length()` you need `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length)` (since Java 1.6).

As an aside there may be not only one valid way to “remove adjacent duplicates”. For example:

- [3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] → [3, 1, 1, 3, 3] → [3, 1, 1] → [3]
- [3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3] → [3, 1, 1, 3, 3] → [3, 3, 3] → []

Another example:

- [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1] → [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] → [1, 1, 1] → []
- [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1] → [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] → [2, 2, 1] → [1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive solution:

```
    public static int[] removeUtil(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                return removeUtil(combineTwoArray(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, i), Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i + 2, arr.length)));
            }
        }
        return arr;

    }

    public static int[] combineTwoArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length + arr2.length);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            newArr[arr1.length + j] = arr2[j];
        }
        return newArr;
    }
```

Comment: this only runs over over iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeDuplicates(new int[] {2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1})));
        }

         public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
             int[] stack = new int[arr.length];

             int i = 0;

             for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.length ; j++) {

                 int currentNumber = arr[j];
                 if(i > 0 && stack[i-1] == currentNumber) {
                     i--;
                 }else {
                     stack[i] = currentNumber;
                     i++;
                 }

             }
             return Arrays.copyOfRange(stack , 0 , i);
         }

    }
```

***Result of the program is :***

```
   Input is [2,3,3] - output is [2]

   input is [1,2,3,3,2] - output is [1]

   input is [2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1] - output is []
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution which do not use recursion.
And using list instead of String, this should avoid any conversion error (int<->String).

```
 static int [] remover(int [] str){
        //List to hold result
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<str.length-1; i++){
            if(str[i]!=str[i+1])
                l.add(str[i]);   //keep adjacent distinct value
        }
        l.add(str[str.length-1]);   //add last value
        //convert list to array back
        return l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
```